# taking a picture and displaying on the view

Tags: extjs, cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a button, and when the user clicks on it, the camera opens the user should be able to take a picture, and then display it on the view.

When the user clicks the button, the following method gets executed;

```
imageButtonClicked: function () {
// This is where I should be calling the camera, taking the pic and displaying on the view
}
```

1. I found this tutorial that explains how to take a photo. But I don't understand which code I should paste to get the camera function working. Can some one help me out?
2. Once I take the picture, how can I display it on the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it either with [Ext.device.Camera's capture()](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.device.Camera-method-capture) or [Phonegap Camera API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera)

E.g with Phonegap Camera API

You can write the below code inside your `imageButtonClicked : function() {}` method.

```
.....
.....
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
 }); 

function onSuccess(imageData) {
    var image = Ext.getCmp('myImageId');
    image.setSrc("data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData);
}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
.....
.....
```

Comment: Looks good but I'd suggest using FILE_URI as using the DATA_URL can cause out of memory errors on phones that take pictures with high mega pixel cameras.

Comment: Thankyou, i see that the image is here `image.setSrc`, but how could i take this and display it on the view ?

Comment: Hi there, is it possible to embed camera to div in ios phonegap?

Answer (score 2):

In the new iOS 6 ::

The new pimped out Mobile Safari in iOS now supports the "file" input field. Your input field will now be ::

For single files

```
<input type=file accept="image/*">
<input type=file accept="video/*">
```

For multiple files

```
<input type=file multiple>
```

This will open the iOS devices Gallery of photos, and lets you select multiple pics. Here's what it will look like

[image: Screenshot of new file dialog in iOS 6]

Comment: Just for other ppl, this is not supported in phonegap/cordova